# How Can I Add a "Selected" Class Based on URL with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, class, addition, selected

I have a sidebar list of links, code shown below...

```
<div class="WikiCustomNav WikiElement wiki"><a href="/" class="wiki_link">Home</a>
<a href="/Calendar" class="wiki_link">Calendar</a>
<a href="/Science" class="wiki_link">Science</a>
<a href="/Language+Arts" class="wiki_link">Language Arts</a>
<a href="/Video+Page" class="wiki_link">Video Page</a>
<a href="/Code+Page" class="wiki_link">Code Page</a>
<a href="/Geography" class="wiki_link">Geography</a>
<a href="/Western+Day" class="wiki_link_new">Delicious Bookmarks</a>
<a href="/Field+Day" class="wiki_link">Field Day</a>
<a href="/Share+Posts" class="wiki_link">Share Posts</a>
<a href="/Audio+Page" class="wiki_link">Audio Page</a>
<a href="/Map+Page" class="wiki_link">Map Page</a>
<a href="/Staff+Olympics" class="wiki_link">Staff Olympics</a>
<a href="/Scribd+Document" class="wiki_link">Scribd Document</a>
<a href="/Staff+Meetings" class="wiki_link_new">Staff Meetings</a>
<a href="/Staff+Phone+Tree" class="wiki_link_new">Staff Phone Tree</a>
<a href="/Employee+Procedures" class="wiki_link_new">Employee Procedures</a>
<a href="/Student+Handbook" class="wiki_link">Student Handbook</a>
<a href="/Table+Sorter" class="wiki_link">Table Sorter</a>
<a href="/Teachers+Tips" class="wiki_link">Teachers Tips</a>
```

In Wikispaces, both the classes "wiki_link" and "wiki_link_new" are applied by default when adding a new sidebar link.  **I'd like to use jQuery to remove both of those classes, and instead, add a "selected" class to the link if that page is currently being viewed.**

**Also, I would like to remove the div that surrounds the list of links, and replace it with an unordered list, with each link wrapped in a list item**, like so...

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/Calendar">Calendar</a></li>
<li><a href="/Science">Science</a></li>
<li>and so on...</li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this with jQuery?  Thanks for your help!